# Javascript/Jquery Syntax to Disable Text Selection on a Div AND all Child Elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

What is the syntax to disable text selection on a div and all of it's sub elements.  I'm using $("#MyContent).disableSelection() to disable all of the text in the below code and it works in firefox and disable all three lines at once.

In IE explorer 9 it doesn't work on child elements so to disable all of the text I'd have to do $("#text1).disableSelection(), $("#text2).disableSelection(), $("#text3).disableSelection().  What is the syntax to disable or apply this to all children at once?

```
<div id="MyContent">
  <div id="text1">Hello World</div>
  <div id="text2">Goodbye</div>
  <div id="text3">Asdf</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @gideon, those are not exact duplicates, as his question is to resolve an issue regarding Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Austin Yea I'm sorry Ray, yea I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```js
$('#MyContent').children().each(function(i, c) {
    disableSelection(c);
});

function disableSelection(target) {
    console.debug(target);

    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined")             // For IE
        target.onselectstart = function() { return false };
    else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined")  // For Firefox
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    else                                                        // All other routes (Opera, etc.).
        target.onmousedown = function() { return false };

    target.style.cursor = "default";
}
```

**Demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/9vLFD/4/

Comment: That works for the most part.  In IE if you start selecting text outside of MyContent and drag it down into MyContent you'll still be able to select the text inside of MyContent.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
$('#MyContent').children().each(function(i,c){
    $(c).disableSelection();
});
```

Comment: Would this even need to run through an `each` call? Maybe just `.children().disableSelection()` should be good. Or the mighty catch all: `$('#MyContent *').disableSelection()`!!! /evillaugh